My headmark does not appear on odd pages
I'using
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Capítulo 1}
\lipsum[1-15]
    
\end{document}

I would like to know why the \ihead{\headmark} command is only working on even pages. The chapter title is not appearing on odd pages.
Page numbers are correct
Thank you in advance for your help!

As always here, please provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and test on their own. We cannot do that with your code.

In a new project, paste the bits that you've pasted here.  And then paste the 5 more lines of code needed to make this compile.  And then use lipsum to get enough text to get several pages of the chapter.  Is it possible that \headmark isn't appearing on page 1, but does appear on page 3?

Doesn’t appear in any odd pages. There’s more than 100 Pages.

I will redo the question by putting all the code using the lipsum package, as the @daleif  suggested.

In the option to add a comment here, right below the answer that solves the problem (and where I am now writing), a pop-up appears telling me to avoid saying "thank you".
Since this was my first question and it was answered with such care and promptness, I can't help but thank @cabohah for the detailed explanation. If this is prohibited, or if there is another place for this type of comment, someone from the forum please let me know. But I can't help but thank you: it really works very well!

Instead of posting a “Thank you” as a comment or an additional answer, we thank by upvoting answers (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓ as you've already done). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so “thank you” answers are removed from public view. “Thank you” comments are also not needed.

\headmark is \leftmark on even pages and \rightmark on odd pages. And with \automark{chapter} you are only defining the section level of the left mark. So in your example \chaptermark is defined to only set the chapter as left mark (using the internal \@mkboth which is the same as \markboth in your case, so it also clears the right mark).
If you want to also set the section level of the right mark, you need to replace \automark{chapter} by \automark[chapter]{chapter}:
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}% set right and left mark
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}% Better use \setparsizes or maybe option parskip → KOMA-Script manual

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Capítulo 1}
\lipsum[1-15]
    
\end{document}

If you instead want \leftmark on odd pages you need to replace \headmark by \leftmark:
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}% set left mark only
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}% use left mark on even and odd pages

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}% Better use \setparsizes or maybe option parskip → KOMA-Script manual

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Capítulo 1}
\lipsum[1-15]
    
\end{document}

Note: If you additionally want section marks after starting a section inside the chapter see the example in the KOMA-Script manuals.
